# Base the "Please consider adding a comment ..." popup on maximum SE reputation

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, popups

When downvoting an answer on Super User, I got the "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." pop-up.

Apparently, the message is based on my Super User reputation (215) and not on my maximum Stack Exchange reputation (3166 on Stack Overflow).

Since the user interface of Super User is the same as that for Stack Overflow, and I don't need reminding of how to use the site in Stack Overflow, I shouldn't need reminding in Super User.

Comment: This would certainly be in the same spirit as the +100 account association bonus.

Comment: How often is this shown? Troyen commented it's more than once, which  [might be true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75966/proposal-to-solve-the-uncommented-downvote-problem/76028#76028). (Though [other sources](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373) suggest it's only shown once.)

Comment: Ah, Jeff confirmed [in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373): *"shown on every downvote until you get to 2k"*.

Comment: @Arjan yes, I see this on every downvote on sites where I'm lower-rep, and any time I upvote an answer to one of my questions I get the "remember you can accept this!" popup.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246927/162102

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this too and [asked about the threshold for these messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246927/162102) before being pointed at this question.

These messages are about how the SE platform operates; they're about voting, commenting, and accepting answers, not about anything site-specific.  So once you've learned those things on one site you don't need to relearn them on another.  Yet, according to [an answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246933/162102) and comments here, you'll get these messages until you reach 2000 rep.  That's way too high for your *second* (or later) time through.

While it would be a lower threshold than what we have now, which requires you to get to 2000 *somewhere*, I propose that the granting of an association bonus should remove these reminders.  By then you've gained 200 reputation on one site, which isn't as much as 2000 but also doesn't mean you just walked in off the street (probably -- and if you did and got lucky with a popular post, other users will likely tell you what you're doing wrong).

An alternative would be to check for 2000 on any associated site (not in real time; this could be cached).  That's more work but preserves the "it takes 2000 rep to really learn the ropes" idea if that's important.

I suggest testing the association-bonus approach.