# Make the "established user" privilege StackExchange-wide

Tags: feature-request, privileges, vote-count

I've acquired the "established user" privilege a few years ago on StackOverflow. And for some reason I start expanding on several other sites of StackExchange. I'm getting used to each of those so I get upvotes, downvotes, etc. But am I focusing on one site to get quickly reputation on that one? Nope, I'm using the palette of sites for what it is. Though I'd like to break it down to understand what I'm doing good (mostly upvotes), bad (mostly downvotes) and controversial (mixed upvotes and downvotes), and viewing upvotes and downvotes is a great tool for that. But that action is apparently still resource-expensive and it is still reserved to established users of a single StackExchange site.

So I'm wondering if the "established user" privilege might be extended to be StackExchange-wide. Maybe not in its entirety, but in a more restricted form that allows users to only see their own posts score breakdown.

A larger request would be to entirely reconsider [this similar proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/please-enable-low-rep-users-to-easily-breakout-up-and-down-votes-on-their-own-qu) (which is 5 years old), especially knowing that it's possible today to see the score of a question or an answer evolving "live".

Comment: Kind of related (if you're thinking of other privs and not just seeing votes): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246927/im-a-high-rep-user-on-other-sites-do-i-need-to-be-tutored-on-new-ones